# How to route to a image in a subfolder of my view

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I tried it get access on a image-path in my codeigniter project but all my tries failed.

I've the following situation.

This is my view-folder

```
admin/myfunction
```

Inside this I have a folder in which all image stored

```
admin/myfunction/content/1/assets
```

I tried to include inside my function (controller/model) a html file. In this file is a link

```
<img scr="content/1/myfile.jpg">
```

To route this, I add the following code into my config->routes.php

```
$route['content/(:num)/(:any)'] = "admin/myfunction/content/$1/assets/$2";
```

This way failed, I recieved 404 page not found.

I think I did something wrong or I have forgot something else?

Thanks for helping me to find the bug.

Comment: image folder inside the view?

Comment: yes, i thought it is easier to have all in one folder

Comment: No. It is not a good approach. Use the directoty inside or outside the application folder but not in view like application->content->1->assets

Comment: and how i can link to this if i have the link scr="content/1/myfile.jpg" from the file?

Comment: could you give me a example,how it could work, also how i can prevent access from outside at for example the public upload-folder?

Answer (score 0):

First, set `base_url()` in `application->config->config.php` file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/example/com';
```

And remove `index.php` from it

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Second, set helper function in `application->config->autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Suppose you have created a directory `application->content->assets`

Now get an image from it like this

```
<img src="<?= base_url('content/assets/imagename.jpg')?>" alt="Image" />
```

Comment: thanks a lot - is there a way to prevend access from outside to this folder - thats one of the reason why i want use the folder in the view

Comment: what you means by this `outside to this folder` ?

Comment: if a have the file in a public folder mydomain.com/pictures
anyone can access to this, i want that you only access to the file, if the call comes from the codeigniter modell/controller

Comment: `base_url('view/pictures')` is also a way to get pictures from folder inside the view

Comment: how this will work - wich path i have to use for this?

Comment: Change permission from `htaccess` file. For live change permission from server

Comment: could you explain me how base_url('view/pictures') works, wich path i have to use and did i have to change the routes.php for that?

Comment: 1. `base_url() = application folder`. 2. `base_url('view') = application/view folder` and so on.

Comment: but it wont work if there a route-rule wich catch for example "image" from base_url(application/view/image) - or did i missunderstand it

Comment: For an image, the route is not required. you can get an image without the route. But for all this project should be properly configured